# VitualBox not detecting my USB devices with a linux host

Tags: virtualbox, usb-device

Since I installed virtualbox 5.0.40 on a mint 18.2 (mate) box I have not been able to connect my usb devices to my virtual machines I have added guest additions and in my usb configurations I select USB3.0 (I tried other settings as well but nothing) but from my virtual machines menu>Devices>USB I get get an empty list.

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the **VirtualBox Extension Pack** to use USB functionalities. Check if you have it installed: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing

The VirtualBox 5.0.40 version is no longer supported (*ended 2017/05*), so it's recommended that you upgrade your VirtualBox too.
However, if you do not wish to update your VirtualBox, you can download the respective **Extension Pack** here: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.40/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.40-115130.vbox-extpack

**EDIT [SOLUTION]:**
As discussed in the comments the problem was solved adding the Linux user that starts VirtualBox to the `vboxusers` group.

Comment: I have already installed the extension pack. In the settings I select USB3.0 but from my virtual machine when I go to devices>USB it does not show any of my attached devices

Comment: Check if your Linux user is included in the `vboxusers` group (to check it you can use  the command `groups myuser`). If not, run `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers myuser`, reopen VirtualBox and check the USB devices again.